# iOS App crashes / Xcode shows no backtrace (Paused)

Tags: ios, xcode4.2

I'm trying to debug a crash (likely memory related) but whenever the app crashes while debugging on iPad device Xcode (4.2) shows Paused with no backtrace for any thread (GDB).  Switching to LLDB provides even less -- the app crashes, console shows nothing and Xcode ends debugging.

The crash only occurs after intense use and is likely related to insufficient memory.

I can't find any info related to the crash though. Anyone else experienced this behavior?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you set the exception breakpoint?

1. got to breakpoint editor pane
2. click on the [+] in the bottom left corner of the pane
3. choose add exception breakpoint

Now you should see a stacktrace if an exception occurs.

Comment: Yes, and I enabled break on exceptions.  On a side note, I found  a rather nasty leak, the solution of which has prevented me from seeing this again.  It's still a bit worrisome though.

Comment: +1 for this. I don't know why this has been disabled for me in XCode recent builds, but It's been ages since I've seen a stacktrace due to this issue. Awesome suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

"Appearing after intensive use" indicates to excessive memory usage and memory leaks, and not that not enough memory is available.

Run the application on your device with instruments running and turn on the leaks module to find where you are not freeing allocated memory.